# How do I compare 2 lists and order 1 based on the number of matches

Tags: python

Say you had a list, for example:

```
first_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And you had the following list:

```
second_list = ['a', 'a b c', 'abc zyx', 'ab cc ac']
```

How would you create a function that simply re-orders the second list based on the total number of times an element from the entire first list matches any part of an individual string from the second list?

---

**For further clarity:**

- in the second list the 'a' string would contain 1 match
- the 'a b c' string would contain 3 matches
- the second example list would essentially end up in reverse order once the function has finished

---

**My attempt:**

```
first_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
second_list = ['a', 'a b c', 'abc zyx', 'ab cc ac']

print second_list

i = 0
for keyword in first_list:
    matches = 0
    for s in second_list:
        matches += s.count(keyword)
        if matches > second_list[0].count(keyword):
            popped = second_list.pop(i)
            second_list.insert(0, popped)

print second_list
```

Comment: Could you please share your own attempt with us?

Comment: I added my attempt @QuakeCore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar answer:

```
first_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']    
second_list = ['a', 'a b c', 'abc zyx', 'ab cc ac']

#Find occurrences
list_for_sorting = []
for string in second_list:
    occurrences = 0
    for item in first_list:
        occurrences += string.count(item)

    list_for_sorting.append((occurrences, string))

#Sort list
sorted_by_occurrence = sorted(list_for_sorting, key=lambda tup: tup[0], reverse=True)
final_list = [i[1] for i in sorted_by_occurrence]
print(final_list)

['ab cc ac', 'a b c', 'abc zyx', 'a']
```

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward approach would be to use the [`key` parameter of the `sorted` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> sorted(second_list, key = lambda s: sum(s.count(x) for x in first_list), reverse=True)
['ab cc ac', 'a b c', 'abc zyx', 'a']
```

The key function is called once per item in the list to be sorted. Still this is inefficient since `count` takes linear time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one unstable way to do it:

```
>>> l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l2 = ['a', 'a b c', 'abc zyx', 'ab cc ac']
>>> [s for _, s in sorted(((sum(s2.count(s1) for s1 in l1), s2) for s2 in l2), reverse=True)]
['ab cc ac', 'abc zyx', 'a b c', 'a']
```

If stable sort is required you could leverage `enumerate`:

```
>>> l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l2 = ['a', 'a b c', 'ccc ccc', 'bb bb bb', 'aa aa aa']
>>> [x[-1] for x in sorted(((sum(s2.count(s1) for s1 in l1), -i, s2) for i, s2 in enumerate(l2)), reverse=True)]
['ccc ccc', 'bb bb bb', 'aa aa aa', 'a b c', 'a']
```

Above generates tuples where second item is a string from `l2` and first item is the count of matches from `l1`:

```
>>> tuples = [(sum(s2.count(s1) for s1 in l1), s2) for s2 in l2]
>>> tuples
[(1, 'a'), (3, 'a b c'), (3, 'abc zyx'), (6, 'ab cc ac')]
```

Then those tuples are sorted to descending order:

```
>>> tuples = sorted(tuples, reverse=True)
>>> tuples
[(6, 'ab cc ac'), (3, 'abc zyx'), (3, 'a b c'), (1, 'a')]
```

And finally only the strings are taken:

```
>>> [s for _, s in tuples]
['ab cc ac', 'abc zyx', 'a b c', 'a']
```

In the second version tuples have reverse index to ensure stability:

```
>>> [(sum(s2.count(s1) for s1 in l1), -i, s2) for i, s2 in enumerate(l2)]
[(1, 0, 'a'), (3, -1, 'a b c'), (3, -2, 'abc zyx'), (6, -3, 'ab cc ac')]
```

Comment: Why is this unstable?

Comment: Because the string from `l2` is the second item of the tuples being sorted so if counts are equal it will be used to decide the ordering.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding this code, sorry

Comment: It seems to me the most straightforward way to do stable-sort is simply: `sorted(second_list, key = lambda s: sum(s.count(x) for x in first_list), reverse=True)`

Comment: Yes but you'd need to count the items from `l1` for every compare, my code does it only once per string on `l2`.

Comment: @niemmi ah, I missed that you had a tuple there. I see now. Anyway, I don't think OP needed exactly that output. From the specification given, the straightforward way makes more sense to me.

Comment: @niemmi Hmm, it seems to me like you would be counting the same number of times in both approaches.

Comment: @niemmi To elaborate, I believe that key function is called precisely once per item in the list to be sorted, not for each comparison in the sorting algorithm.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're absolutely correct, I tried this on Python 2.7 with custom key function that tracked the amount of calls. It seems that Python outsmarted me in this one :)

Comment: @niemmi Yes, I just confirmed it [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) as well. I think it would be silly to have such an efficient, adaptive mergesort  like Timsort under the hood and then call a key-function for every comparison.